# Transfer WordPress site from local to production site

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use WordPress to design and work on my new website, but I would like to test it on my local machine before I get the first version. So I thought about installing WordPress on my MacBook running OS X Lion and working then on it.

Once I am happy with my website, will it be easy to "transfer" it to the definitive site?

Comment: You should ask questions about managing your website on [webmasters.se]. But before you just copy and paste this one search the site to see if there's already an answer to your question there. Also you'll probably need to give more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two popular ways (among others) to transfer a dev WP site to production:

1. copy all files to your destination server and then deal with the data issues by going into mysql and updating the urls (via find and replace) to thenew url
2. alternatively, you can just simply install a new version of wordpress on the destination server and do a data import (which imports a file that was *exported* from your other WP site using the wordpress export tool http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen)

Answer (score 1):

If the website is started from scratch, simply just copy all the files from the folder where your local installation of Wordpress is located in directly to the destination server, just change paths and the database accordingly after you have done so.